# how to prevent the arduino from overwriting

Tags: arduino

i'm just asking if it is possible to write-protect the arduino from overwriting.
I am using the serial for communication between the computer and arduino so it has to be plug the usb all the time. The problem is how can i protect it form overwriting?

is there any way to Enable/Disable the upload sketch?

assuming, my sketch is final i don't want to somebody could write in it. unless i unlock it. so usb serial only use for getting information from the arduino.

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the following ways:

1. **disable (unprogram) the SPIEN fuse bit**; this approach requires an external ISP programmer to enable it later and since most modern PCs don't have the LPT port available getting a USB programmer (e.g. ATAVRISP2) may be unacceptable due to additional cost
2. **disable auto reset during serial programming**: can be done in many ways e.g.

   a) by adding 10uF capacitor between GND and reset pin (with a switch or jumper)

   b) by removing the .1uF capacitor connecting the DTR line to reset from the board

My favorite approach is 2.a

Comment: Any details on how to implement option 1? I have PICkit 4 programmer that can also be used for AVR MCUs, how would I use it to change that bit? I simply want to make it impossible to use USB port to have direct read/write access to FLASH memory of MCU (I am making external password manager that is supposed to be virus resistant, so I need to make it impossible for virus on PC to overwrite or read flash of MCU using USB)

Comment: Take a look at this calculator: https://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/ and utilize e.g. avrdude tool to program the uC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using serial just to get the data from Arduino, set the RX pin to HIGH.

Sample:

```
char pinRX = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pinRX, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinRX, HIGH);
  ...
  ...
}
```

This method will make your Arduino be read-only but be careful.

The micro-controller will be unwritable in ordinary way so I recommend you to prepare some methods for making the RX pin LOW. (e.x. interruption by button)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an UNO or ATmega328 clone.
The processor is remotely rebooted into bootloader by the toggling of the serial ports DTR. This normally occurs when an application connects to the COM port (or ttyS on Linux). In addition to the other methods mentioned in other answers, this DTR can be prevented via several methods.

**CUT THE DTR:**
Either remove the capacitor labeled C5 or cut the cut-able jumper labeled "RESET-EN" between to pads. Either of these will severe the DTR of the Serial Port, no longer driving the reset of the Arduino to reboot to the bootloader.

**DONT SET DTR:**
That said you may be able to configure your Hosting application driving the Serial Port not to assert DTR. Several terminal apps can be configured to "NOT USE DTR". This would have the same affect as the above. And would have the elegant benefit of no code changes to make it work and not work. Simply run the No DTR application for your solution. And run the IDE when you want to program or debug it.

**USE A LEONARDO:**
Note a Leonardo or other ATmega32u4 based Arduino has a virtual Serial Port inside its USB driver. Where it does not have a DTR that can cause a external hard reset. Rather its remote reboot method is to temporarily connect to it at 1200 baud, after which it reboots into the boot loader at higher baud rate. Where I doubt your host application will ever do this. So using a Leo will likely meet your needs with out any changes to anything.